CalledProcessError: Command '['ninja']' returned non-zero exit status 1
I'm trying to import spconv.pytorch in my project, but I encounter a compilation error related to TensorView. Here’s the error output I’m getting:
FAILED: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/include/tensorview_bind/TensorViewBind.h.gch 
g++ -MMD -MT /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/include/tensorview_bind/TensorViewBind.h.gch -MF /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/include/tensorview_bind/TensorViewBind.h.gch.d -I "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/include" -I "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pybind11/include" -I "/usr/include/python3.10" -I "/usr/local/cuda/include" -I "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/include" -O3 -std=c++14 -fPIC -x c++-header -DTV_CUDA -c /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/include/tensorview_bind/TensorViewBind.h -o /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/include/tensorview_bind/TensorViewBind.h.gch
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/include/tensorview_bind/TensorViewBind.h:1:9: warning: #pragma once in main file
    1 | #pragma once
      |         ^~~~
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/include/tensorview_bind/TensorViewBind.h:2:10: fatal error: tensorview/pybind_utils.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <tensorview/pybind_utils.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
[2/39] [GCC][c++/pch]/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/include/csrc/arrayref/ArrayPtr.h.gch
FAILED: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/include/csrc/arrayref/ArrayPtr.h.gch 
g++ -MMD -MT /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/include/csrc/arrayref/ArrayPtr.h.gch -MF /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/include/csrc/arrayref/ArrayPtr.h.gch.d -I "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/include" -I "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pybind11/include" -I "/usr/include/python3.10" -I "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/include" -I "/usr/local/cuda/include" -O3 -std=c++14 -fPIC -x c++-header -DTV_CUDA -c /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/include/csrc/arrayref/ArrayPtr.h -o /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/include/csrc/arrayref/ArrayPtr.h.gch
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/include/csrc/arrayref/ArrayPtr.h:1:9: warning: #pragma once in main file
    1 | #pragma once
      |         ^~~~
In file included from /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/include/csrc/arrayref/ArrayPtr.h:3:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/include/common/TensorViewCPU.h:3:10: fatal error: tensorview/core/all.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <tensorview/core/all.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
[3/39] [GCC][c++]/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/src/tensorview_bind/PyBindTensorViewBind/PyBindTensorViewBind_bind_TensorViewBind.cc.o
FAILED: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/src/tensorview_bind/PyBindTensorViewBind/PyBindTensorViewBind_bind_TensorViewBind.cc.o 
g++ -MMD -MT /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/src/tensorview_bind/PyBindTensorViewBind/PyBindTensorViewBind_bind_TensorViewBind.cc.o -MF /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/src/tensorview_bind/PyBindTensorViewBind/PyBindTensorViewBind_bind_TensorViewBind.cc.o.d -I "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/include" -I "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pybind11/include" -I "/usr/include/python3.10" -I "/usr/local/cuda/include" -I "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/include" -O3 -std=c++14 -fPIC -DTV_CUDA -c /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/src/tensorview_bind/PyBindTensorViewBind/PyBindTensorViewBind_bind_TensorViewBind.cc -o /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/src/tensorview_bind/PyBindTensorViewBind/PyBindTensorViewBind_bind_TensorViewBind.cc.o
In file included from /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/src/tensorview_bind/PyBindTensorViewBind/PyBindTensorViewBind_bind_TensorViewBind.cc:2:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cumm/build/core_cc/include/tensorview_bind/TensorViewBind.h:2:10: fatal error: tensorview/pybind_utils.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <tensorview/pybind_utils.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-0c1e6eb5644d> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import spconv.pytorch as spconv

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ccimport/buildtools/writer.py in build_simple_ninja(target, build_dir, sources, build_meta, target_filename, suffix_to_compiler, out_root, verbose, shared, pch_to_sources, pch_to_include, objects_folder, compiler_to_path, linker_to_path, source_meta, linker)
   1107     proc.wait()
   1108     if proc.returncode:
-> 1109         raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, cmds)
   1110 
   1111     no_work_to_do = False

CalledProcessError: Command '['ninja']' returned non-zero exit status 1.    

Here are some details about my environment:
Python version: 3.10
CUDA version: 11.7
spconv version: 2.3.6
tried with tensorview version: 0.4.0 and 0.2.0
I have tried reinstalling the spconv package and ensuring that all dependencies are met, but the issue persists.
